# Python multi-threading start and stop

Tags: python, multithreading

I have wrote a program in Python about threading and listed as follow. However, it seems that the thread does not run. When I run the program, it shows message "Thread Completed". What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from threading import Thread

class timer:  

    def __init__(self):  
        self._running = True  

    def terminate(self):  
        self._running = False  

    def run(self, n):   
            mycount=0
            #while self._running:  
        while mycount < 10:
            mycount=mycount+1
                print(n)

#start a thread
c = timer()
t = Thread(target=c.run, args=("One!!",))
t.start

while(1):

   if t.is_alive():
      print("Thread still running")
   else:
      print("Thread Completed")

   mya=raw_input("Input, a=stop thread b=start thread c=quit program   ")
   if mya=="a":
      c.terminate()
   if mya=="b":
      c = timer()
      t = Thread(target=c.run, args=("Two!!",))
      t.start
   if mya=="c":
      break
```

Comment: `t.start()` instead of `t.start`

Comment: Even with a proper `start` call, the `run` function may need a `time.sleep(0.1)` or so to actually take some "real" time to complete...

Comment: I have amend the code to t.start() and add time.sleep(0.5) in the run function, it can start the thread. However, the thread can't stop even I add "c.terminate()" So, how can stop a thread?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change while loop inside run method to this:

```
while mycount < 10:
    mycount=mycount+1
    time.sleep(1) # sleep for 1 second
print(n)
```

Don't forget to import time module at the beginning of the script.
With this, your thread will loop for 10 sec. Start thread with`t.start()` as
@Tim Castelijns suggested.

Comment: *your thread will loop every second* it will not even start if he doesn't call `t.start()` properly

Comment: Thanks, it can start the thread according to your comment. But how to terminate the thread when I change the code at above to: While self._running